# Can "sendkeys" be used in place of "select" for dropdown in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can "sendkeys" be used in place of "select" for dropdown in selenium webdriver?

If yes then why is select used?

Comment: I know you can use `click()` with proper selector by using specific selector. What makes you think `sendKeys()` can also be used as well?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Can you post some code with what you have tried or link the methods you are asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually depend on the dropdown. If your drop down have textfield then yes you can sendkeys and if dropdown is not having text box then you can't.

In below code I am adding two dropbox example. click on "Run Code Snippet". For 1st one you can't use sendkeys while for 2nd Yes you can.

Hope it will help you :)

Get back to me if still having any issue :)

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Select Example by Index value</title>
</head>
<body>
<select name="Mobiles"><option value="0" selected> Please select</option>
<option value="1">iPhone</option>
<option value="2">Nokia</option>
<option value="3">Samsung</option>
<option value="4">HTC</option>
<option value="5">BlackBerry</option>
</select></body></html</br>

<input list="hosting-plan" type="text">
 
<datalist id="hosting-plan">
 <option value="small"/>
 <option value="medium"/>
 <option value="large"/>
</datalist>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <select tabindex="1" onchange="changeCode('txtCollPostCode', 'ConsignorAddressCountryId');" name="Consignor.Address.CountryId" id="ConsignorAddressCountryId">
<option value="207" title="GREAT BRITAIN" selected="selected">GREAT BRITAIN</option>
<option value="211" title="UNITED STATES">UNITED STATES</option>
<option value="1068" title="AFGHANISTAN">AFGHANISTAN</option>
<option value="222" title="ALBANIA">ALBANIA</option>
<option value="2" title="ALGERIA">ALGERIA</option>
</select>

Comment: Oh Yes... Actually sendkeys set value in HTML DOM itself.  so it can work in some places . Do you know you can upload files too using sendkeys :)

Comment: Though its not allowed on this forum but anyways thanks for being so helpful.

Comment: welcome and thanks :) . one thing more. there a many ways to create a dropdown such like using div tags and using li etc so in such case sendkeys may not work. As said its depends.